# Stuck--image grid layout and media-queries for responsive design

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm working on a site by hand coding for the first time (mainly a print designer). I'm trying to only use HTML and CSS, as I haven't had the time to dive into any Javascript and I really want to understand what I'm using. So, my main content is set up in a grid of images, all the same size, 3 columns wide.

I'd like to use media queries for responsive design with different browser/device sizes. Best I understand this, you create different CSS files for the same HTML layout that load depending on the size of the device/browser.

As it is now, each image in the grid is set inside a div as an a tag. I then used CSS to define the image with the background property.

```
<div id="main-content">
    <div id="project-1">
        <a id="image-1" href="URL here"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="project-2">
        <a id="image-2" href="URL here"></a>
    </div>
    ...etc.

#image-1 {
    background: url(image.png) no-repeat;
    width: x;
    height: y;
}

...etc.
```

After a bit of research, it sounds like this is not a good solution; it's better to use the  tag in the HTML itself.

My question is, am I going about this the wrong way? I'm a little confused about where to put the images so that I can modify the layout with media queries. Thanks in advance for any advice. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This looks absolutely fine to me.

The only thing I'd do in your case is to add the images with an `<img>` tag inside the `<a>` in your HTML and give them all the same class, instead of putting them all in individually via CSS, as then when you define the media queries for your responsive layouts you'd only have to modify the `width` and `height` for that one class and your images would all scale accordingly. You'll just be saving yourself a bit of work.

I hope this is relatively clear. :)

Comment: Clear as day, thanks. One thing I didn't mention is I was hoping to use image sprites and a transition to give each image a greyscale--color rollover effect. the only solution I've seen for this is using CSS, which would cause a problem if I only identified the image using an image tag in HTML. Is there a way to do this with your method, or am I looking at a more complicated solution?

Comment: Yeah, you can do the grey effect with CSS3. Add this code to your image class and then when you hover over it just set `grayscale(0%)`. That way you won't have to upload two versions of your images either.

`filter: grayscale(100%);
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
-ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
-o-filter: grayscale(100%);`

This doesn't work on IE though. Check this link http://www.karlhorky.com/2012/06/cross-browser-image-grayscale-with-css.html, but I haven't tested it yet.

I'm not very confident with sprites though, so I'm afraid I can't help you with that. :(

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. Will I still be able to use a 1 second rollover transition between the two states? I much prefer it over a hard change between the two.

Comment: Yeah, you can still use transitions. Just add them to both the normal and the hover state, that way it will be smooth both ways.

Comment: I've got the first bit worked out with grayscale images going to full color on rollover...how exactly would I add the transition bit of code to give it a smooth 1 sec trans? I'm also a bit wary of using this method as Chrome is the only browser with support currently. Any other solutions that are more accepted currently?

Comment: You could use CSS3 transitions to do that, but yeah, they're only supported in modern browsers. Go to this link and fill in the options for transitions. http://css3generator.com/ 

It will automatically generate your code and just put it in your `:hover` and normal states in your CSS. I'm not sure if there's a workaround without using JavaScript or jQuery to support other browsers too though.